# How to get current Location(latitude , longitude) while gps is off using FusedLocationApi in android

Tags: android, gps, location

I have used latest api. I have implement FusedLocationApi and i am getting current location if gps is on. I have connected with google play services still i am not getting current location.

I use this code:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class GPSTracker implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private OnLocationChangedListener mLocationChangedListener;

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final float MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES / 2;
    private final Context mContext;
    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    // Current best location estimate
    private Location mBestReading;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude


    public void setLocationChangedListener(OnLocationChangedListener listener) {
        mLocationChangedListener = listener;
    }


    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the addApi() method to request the LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mCurrentLocation != null)
                canGetLocation = true;
        }

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
        // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
        // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
        // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES);

        // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
        // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }


    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            latitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        }
        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            longitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
     * lauch Settings Options
     */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    /**
     * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
        // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
        // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.

        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    /**
     * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location mCurrentLocation) {
        canGetLocation = true;
        this.mCurrentLocation = mCurrentLocation;
        mLocationChangedListener.onReceiveLocation(mCurrentLocation, 1);
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
                canGetLocation = true;
                mLocationChangedListener.onReceiveLocation(mCurrentLocation, 1);
            }
        }
        if (mCurrentLocation == null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    public interface OnLocationChangedListener {
        void onReceiveLocation(Location receiveLocation, int resultCode);
    }

}
```

Here is the code. While GPS is off  onLocationChanged(Location location) callback method not called by Api.

Answer (score 0):

Without the GPS is not possible to update the current lat long. The below code is working when the GPS is on but in some case the GPS is able to track the current lat long in the case the AGPS is fetching the lat long from the wifi connection or telecom network and it will only work when the device have the AGPS hardware.

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Getting Location Updates.
 *
 * Demonstrates how to use the Fused Location Provider API to get updates about a device's
 * location. The Fused Location Provider is part of the Google Play services location APIs.
 *
 * For a simpler example that shows the use of Google Play services to fetch the last known location
 * of a device, see
 * https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/BasicLocation.
 *
 * This sample uses Google Play services, but it does not require authentication. For a sample that
 * uses Google Play services for authentication, see
 * https://github.com/googlesamples/android-google-accounts/tree/master/QuickStart.
 */
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    protected static final String TAG = "location-updates-sample";

    /**
     * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
     */
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    /**
     * The fastest rate for active location updates. Exact. Updates will never be more frequent
     * than this value.
     */
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    // Keys for storing activity state in the Bundle.
    protected final static String REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY = "requesting-location-updates-key";
    protected final static String LOCATION_KEY = "location-key";
    protected final static String LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY = "last-updated-time-string-key";

    /**
     * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Stores parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
     */
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;

    // UI Widgets.
    protected Button mStartUpdatesButton;
    protected Button mStopUpdatesButton;
    protected TextView mLastUpdateTimeTextView;
    protected TextView mLatitudeTextView;
    protected TextView mLongitudeTextView;

    /**
     * Tracks the status of the location updates request. Value changes when the user presses the
     * Start Updates and Stop Updates buttons.
     */
    protected Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;

    /**
     * Time when the location was updated represented as a String.
     */
    protected String mLastUpdateTime;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Locate the UI widgets.
        mStartUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_updates_button);
        mStopUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_updates_button);
        mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_text);
        mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_text);
        mLastUpdateTimeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_update_time_text);

        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        mLastUpdateTime = "";

        // Update values using data stored in the Bundle.
        updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

        // Kick off the process of building a GoogleApiClient and requesting the LocationServices
        // API.
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        //turnGPSOn();
    }

    /**
     * Updates fields based on data stored in the bundle.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState The activity state saved in the Bundle.
     */
    private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Updating values from bundle");
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Update the value of mRequestingLocationUpdates from the Bundle, and make sure that
            // the Start Updates and Stop Updates buttons are correctly enabled or disabled.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY)) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                        REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY);
                setButtonsEnabledState();
            }

            // Update the value of mCurrentLocation from the Bundle and update the UI to show the
            // correct latitude and longitude.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LOCATION_KEY)) {
                // Since LOCATION_KEY was found in the Bundle, we can be sure that mCurrentLocation
                // is not null.
                mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LOCATION_KEY);
            }

            // Update the value of mLastUpdateTime from the Bundle and update the UI.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY)) {
                mLastUpdateTime = savedInstanceState.getString(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY);
            }
            updateUI();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the
     * LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the location request. Android has two location request settings:
     * {@code ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION} and {@code ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}. These settings control
     * the accuracy of the current location. This sample uses ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, as defined in
     * the AndroidManifest.xml.
     * <p/>
     * When the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION setting is specified, combined with a fast update
     * interval (5 seconds), the Fused Location Provider API returns location updates that are
     * accurate to within a few feet.
     * <p/>
     * These settings are appropriate for mapping applications that show real-time location
     * updates.
     */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
        // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
        // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
        // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
        // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the Start Updates button and requests start of location updates. Does nothing if
     * updates have already been requested.
     */
    public void startUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
            setButtonsEnabledState();
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the Stop Updates button, and requests removal of location updates. Does nothing if
     * updates were not previously requested.
     */
    public void stopUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
            setButtonsEnabledState();
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    /**
     * Ensures that only one button is enabled at any time. The Start Updates button is enabled
     * if the user is not requesting location updates. The Stop Updates button is enabled if the
     * user is requesting location updates.
     */
    private void setButtonsEnabledState() {
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mStartUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
            mStopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mStartUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
            mStopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the latitude, the longitude, and the last location time in the UI.
     */
    private void updateUI() {
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
            mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText(mLastUpdateTime);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
        // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
        // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.

        // The final argument to {@code requestLocationUpdates()} is a LocationListener
        // (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html).
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Within {@code onPause()}, we pause location updates, but leave the
        // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, we resume receiving
        // location updates if the user has requested them.

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

        super.onStop();
    }

    /**
     * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");

        // If the initial location was never previously requested, we use
        // FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation() to get it. If it was previously requested, we store
        // its value in the Bundle and check for it in onCreate(). We
        // do not request it again unless the user specifically requests location updates by pressing
        // the Start Updates button.
        //
        // Because we cache the value of the initial location in the Bundle, it means that if the
        // user launches the activity,
        // moves to a new location, and then changes the device orientation, the original location
        // is displayed as the activity is re-created.
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            updateUI();
        }

        // If the user presses the Start Updates button before GoogleApiClient connects, we set
        // mRequestingLocationUpdates to true (see startUpdatesButtonHandler()). Here, we check
        // the value of mRequestingLocationUpdates and if it is true, we start location updates.
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback that fires when the location changes.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.location_updated_message),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }


    /**
     * Stores activity data in the Bundle.
     */
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY, mRequestingLocationUpdates);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable(LOCATION_KEY, mCurrentLocation);
        savedInstanceState.putString(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY, mLastUpdateTime);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```